# im2txt & TensorFlow 1.4.1

Tags: python, tensorflow

Does anyone here succeed to run im2txt with TensorFlow 1.4.1?

I'm using this model(https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_qCJ40uBfjEWVItOTdyNUFOMzg/view)

```
2018-01-04 00:46:59.268582: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1192] Not found: Key lstm/basic_lstm_cell/kernel not found in checkpoint
```

Then I tried the following script to convert model. The script generated checkpoint, .meta, .data, and .index.

```
OLD_CHECKPOINT_FILE = "/tmp/my_checkpoint/model.ckpt-3000000"
NEW_CHECKPOINT_FILE = "/tmp/my_converted_checkpoint/model.ckpt-3000000"

import tensorflow as tf
vars_to_rename = {
    "lstm/BasicLSTMCell/Linear/Matrix": "lstm/basic_lstm_cell/weights",
    "lstm/BasicLSTMCell/Linear/Bias": "lstm/basic_lstm_cell/biases",
}
new_checkpoint_vars = {}
reader = tf.train.NewCheckpointReader(OLD_CHECKPOINT_FILE)
for old_name in reader.get_variable_to_shape_map():
  if old_name in vars_to_rename:
    new_name = vars_to_rename[old_name]
  else:
    new_name = old_name
  new_checkpoint_vars[new_name] = tf.Variable(reader.get_tensor(old_name))

init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
saver = tf.train.Saver(new_checkpoint_vars)

with tf.Session() as sess:
  sess.run(init)
  print("save checkpoint")
  saver.save(sess, NEW_CHECKPOINT_FILE)
```

Could anyone tell me how I can use those files to run im2txt with TensorFlow 1.4.1. (Actually, I could run im2txt with tensorflow 0.12.1)

Env 
python 3.5.2
Mac OS X version 10.12.6
TensorFlow 1.4.1

Thank for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get the same error with checkpoint file with tf 1.4.1 and python3.5 on MacOS 10.13

Reason: checkpoint file downloaded is generated using an old version of tensorflow(python2). word_count.txt file format

answers from https://github.com/KranthiGV/Pretrained-Show-and-Tell-model

Changes:
1. generate ckp file which can be loaded by tf1.4.1

```
OLD_CHECKPOINT_FILE = "model.ckpt-1000000"
NEW_CHECKPOINT_FILE = "model2.ckpt-1000000"

import tensorflow as tf
vars_to_rename = {
"lstm/basic_lstm_cell/weights": "lstm/basic_lstm_cell/kernel",
"lstm/basic_lstm_cell/biases": "lstm/basic_lstm_cell/bias",
}
new_checkpoint_vars = {}
reader = tf.train.NewCheckpointReader(OLD_CHECKPOINT_FILE)
for old_name in reader.get_variable_to_shape_map():
    if old_name in vars_to_rename:
        new_name = vars_to_rename[old_name]
else:
    new_name = old_name
new_checkpoint_vars[new_name] = 
tf.Variable(reader.get_tensor(old_name))`

init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
saver = tf.train.Saver(new_checkpoint_vars)

with tf.Session() as sess:
   sess.run(init)
   saver.save(sess, NEW_CHECKPOINT_FILE)
```

2. python3 file reading problem, in im2txt/run_reference.py

   `with tf.gfile.GFile(filename, "rb") as f:`
3. word_count.txt downloaded from that link need to be replaced with this one 
   https://github.com/siavash9000/im2txt_demo/tree/master/im2txt_pretrained

Answer (score 0):

Chunfang's solution works for me, but I wanted to share another approach.

In recent versions of TensorFlow, Google provides an "official" [`checkpoint_convert.py`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/rnn/python/tools/checkpoint_convert.py) utility to convert old RNN checkpoints:

```
python checkpoint_convert.py [--write_v1_checkpoint] \
  '/path/to/old_checkpoint' '/path/to/new_checkpoint'
```